# Video Recording in Ionic and Capacitor Application

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, mobile, capacitor

I am developing a mobile application using Ionic, Angular, and Capacitor. And I need a video recording feature where I can record a video or select a video from stored videos in the file system, show its preview, and post those videos to the back end.

And I am using the latest versions of Ionic, Angular, and Capacitor.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Video+Recording+in+Ionic+and+Capacitor+Application

Comment: Hello, @E.Maggini most of them are using old Cordova plugins. I am looking for something that is suitable for the latest version of ionic and capacitor

Answer (score 0):

here's a working capacitor plugin: [capacitor-video-recorder](https://github.com/TeamMaestro/capacitor-video-recorder)